Jupyter notebook kernel crashes when importing xarray
I'm trying to import xarray in my Jupyter Notebook and when I run the cell
import xarray

the following error appears:
"The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell.
Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure.
Click here for more info.
View Jupyter log for further details."
I have tried restarting the kernel several times, uninstalling and reinstalling xarray and even increasing my memory by adding the cell
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"

before the import but none of it has worked. I foun online that it is also possible other dependent packages could cause the package to fall over, and they suggest to start a new environment. Is there a way to solve it without starting a new environment?

I can't reproduce the error. Do the jupyter logs have any details logged at the time of the kernel crash ? and check that your memory is not full

@chickitychinachinesechicken The Jupyter logs say: 19:53:28.248 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason:
19:53:28.276 [info] Cell 1 completed in -1718844806.403s (start: 1718844806403, end: undefined). Memory is not full, it's on its 25%.

How are you installing xarray package? Are you coding within the notebook directly, or using an IDE? Is your Jupyter running locally on your system, or on the cloud? how to do start your notebook, from a terminal command line?

@chickitychinachinesechicken I've tried installing xarray from the terminal using pip install xarray, python3 -m pip install xarray, python3 -m pip install "xarray[complete]", all of them gave the same error. I'm coding within the notebook in VScode. I don't know if VScode runs locally or on the cloud, but I'd say it runs locally. The notebook is started within VScode.

in some online research, I seem to be finding possibly some of the same resources you mention, which may suggest the issue could be related to memory usage.

In trying to reproduce your issue, using pip to install xarray on my Windows 11 machine, xarray pulls in 9 dependencies, including numpy, and pandas, totalling 160 MB. I would suggest creating a virtual environment (virtualenv) to isolate your sytem-wide pip configuration from your jupyter notebook project to prevent too many dependencies getting ran when you run your jupyter notebook, first just get xarray to install successfully, then move it to a jupyter notebook. When running a script with only import xarray, it consumes 70 MB RAM memory on my machine...

@chickitychinachinesechicken I created a virtual environment and it won't work. I think I have to increase the memory available, but what I've tried hasn't worked. I tried adding sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) but Kernel still crashes. Is there another way to increase memory? (I'm working on Mac).

hmm, not sure, one possible thing to try Jupyter Notebook Kernel Keeps dying - low memory?

@chickitychinachinesechicken After trying everything I found online, I solved it. Apparently, it works if I install it with conda, i.e, conda install "xarray[complete]" it works (don't ask me why). Before I was installing it with pip install "xarray[complete]"

Great update @samuel-jaramillo, thanks for sharing the details you used to resolve the issue. Consider posting it as an answer below and accepting it, for other users to that experience the same issue can reference it, and closing this question from the queue would be helpful.

After trying everything I found online, I solved it. None of the methods for increasing the RAM limits for Jupyter Notebook were working. However I installed xarray with conda, i.e, conda install "xarray[complete]" it works. Apparently, this has to do with some prerequisites of the xarray module. Before, I was installing it with pip install "xarray[complete]".

Anaconda/conda is able to do more powerful changes to your system & at higher levels than pip is allowed to do. That may something to do with this.
